# Routing cannot map action parameters correctly

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have this in RouteConfig.cs file:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PreSeleccion",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{month}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Menu", action = "PreSeleccion" }
        );
```

On the other hand, I have this in the `Menu` controller:

```
    // GET: Menu/PreSeleccion/{month}/{id}
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PreSeleccion(int month = 0, int id = 0)
    {

    }
```

When calling that action with this URL: `/Menu/PreSeleccion/202301/80` and debug, I can see that `month` parameter is 0 and the `id` parameter is 202301.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just try changing to url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{month}"

Comment: @viveknuna for design purposes, order should be /{month}/{id}. I know that it should work, but I am sure something is missing here.

Comment: I have finally used attribute routing only for this action, This was how it worked: `[Route("Menu/PreSeleccion/{month:int?}/{id:int?}")]`